# What would be regex for this

Tags: ruby, regex

I have list of website, I want all website with url `http://www.tutorspree.com/tutor/#{AnyNumber)` where after 'tutor' there could be any number. How do I write Regex for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define it with:

```
Regexp.new("^http://www\.tutorspree\.com/tutor/\\d+$")
```

This avoids having to escape the forward slashes. It would be used on a list of URLs like this:

```
tutor_re = Regexp.new("^http://www\.tutorspree\.com/tutor/\\d+$")
list = [ "http://nomatch.com/", "http://www.tutorspree.com/tutor/1", "http://www.tutorspree.com/tutor/2" ]
matches = list.select { |url| tutor_re.match url }
```

Comment: You can also just do: `re = %r{http://www\.etc/}`

Comment: @Phrogz I dislike the `%{}` in general syntax for having too many special characters, so actually did not even remember that it existed for re's as well. =)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
http:\/\/www\.tutorspree\.com\/tutor\/\#\d+
```

ought to work.

Comment: http:\/\/www\.tutorspree\.com\/tutor\/\#\d+